# When using doctrine in phpStorm console it runs in --no-interaction by default

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, phpstorm

I'm having troubles with the console when using PhpStorm in combination with Symfony 2. It runs in --no-interaction mode, and only gives my errors. But when I use the same command in the terminal, it works fine. Somebody knows how I should fix this problem?

In PhpStorm console:

> ➜ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php /Users/job/PhpstormProjects/prop/app/console doctrine:generate:entity
>
> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     The entity name must contain a : ("" given, expecting something like AcmeBlogBundle:Blog/Post)
>
> doctrine:generate:entity [--entity="..."] [--fields="..."] [--format="..."] [--with-repository]
>
> Process finished with exit code 1 at 14:09:35. Execution time: 2.387 ms.

In MacOS terminal it works fine:

> ➜  ~  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php /Users/job/PhpstormProjects/prop/app/console doctrine:generate:entity
>
> <  Welcome to the Doctrine2 entity generator
>
> < This command helps you generate Doctrine2 entities.
>
> < First, you need to give the entity name you want to generate.
>   < You must use the shortcut notation like AcmeBlogBundle:Post.
>
> < The Entity shortcut name:

Comment: 1) What is your IDE version? 2) Which "console" do you use: "Command Line Tools" or "Terminal" ?

Comment: PhpStorm 6.0.3., I tried both. Command Line Tools doesn't work but the code it generates works in Terminal.

Comment: You can always extend `\Symfony\Component\Console\Application` class and override the `configureIO()` method for changing `$input->setInteractive(true);` again depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You are using PhpStorm v6, which means **Command Line Tools**. It indeed has problems with interactive mode, since it only **emulates** terminal (AFAIK). Check and watch this ticket for details:

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16892

If you want to execute such commends from within PhpStorm, I may only suggest to try **v7** which has proper Terminal support (local and remote (SSH)). More details in this blog post:

- http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/09/built-in-local-terminal-in-phpstorm-7/
- also: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/?s=terminal